# Open and close mobile navbar menu using styled components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm following a guide on how to build a simple website using Styled Components.

When the website is in mobile view the hamburger menu is stuck open and will not close when clicking the hamburger symbol or any of the nav menu items. The hamburger symbol does toggle to the `FaTimes` symbol, however.

All solutions I found so far don't work or require bootstrap, which I'm unfamiliar with. Can someone please explain to me the error in my code?

Navbar

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { FaBars, FaTimes } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { Nav, NavbarContainer, NavLogo, NavIcon, MobileIcon, NavItem, NavMenu, NavLinks,
NavItemBtn, NavBtnLink } from './Navbar.elements';
import {Button } from '../globalstyles';
import osun from '../images/Osun.png';
import { IconContext} from 'react-icons/lib';
import Home from './pages/Home';


const Navbar = () => {
    const [click, setClick, isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const [button, setButton] = useState(true);

const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

const hide = () => setIsOpen(false);

const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);

// const toggleShow = () => {
//     this.setState({show: !this.state.show})
// }
//const toggleShow = () => setClick(!show)

// const toggleShow = () => {
//     if (window.innerwidth <= 960){
//         showMenu(false)
//     } else {
//         showMenu(true)
//     }
// }


const showButton = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth <=960){
        setButton(false)
    } else { 
        setButton(true)
    }
};
const closeMobileMenu = () => setClick(false);

useEffect(() => {
    showButton();
    //toggleShow()
}, []);

window.addEventListener('resize', showButton);
//window.addEventListener('resize', toggleShow);
    return (
        <>
        <IconContext.Provider value={{color: "#fff"}}>
        <Nav>
            <NavbarContainer>
                <NavLogo to ="/">
                    <NavIcon />
                    Osun Swap
                </NavLogo>
                <MobileIcon onClick={handleClick} onBlur={hide} >
                    {click ? < FaTimes/> : <FaBars/>}
                    </MobileIcon>
                <NavMenu onClick={handleClick} click ={click}>
                    <NavItem>
                        <NavLinks to = '/' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                            Home
                        </NavLinks>
                    </NavItem>
                    <NavItem>
                        <NavLinks to = '/services' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                            Services
                        </NavLinks>
                    </NavItem>
                    <NavItem>
                        <NavLinks to = '/AboutUs' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                            About us
                        </NavLinks>
                    </NavItem>
                    <NavItemBtn>
                        {button ? (
                            <NavBtnLink to ='/sign-up'>
                                <Button primary> Connect Wallet </Button>
                            </NavBtnLink>
                        ) : (
                            <NavBtnLink to='/sign-up'>
                                <Button onClick={closeMobileMenu} fontBig primary>
                                    Connect Wallet
                                </Button>
                            </NavBtnLink>
                        )}
                    </NavItemBtn>
                </NavMenu>     
            </NavbarContainer>
        </Nav>
        </IconContext.Provider>
        </>
    )
}

export default Navbar;
```

Navbar.elements

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import osun from '../images/Osun.png';
import { Container } from '../globalstyles';

export const Nav = styled.nav`
background : #101522;//#282c34;//rgb(35, 31,32);//; //rgb(10, 10, 10);
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
font-size: 1.2rem;
position: sticky;
top:0;
z-index:999;
`;

export const NavbarContainer = styled(Container)`
display: flex;
justify-content:space-between;
height: 80px;

${Container}
`;

export const NavLogo = styled(Link)`
color: #ffff;
justify-self: flex-start;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 2rem;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
`;
export const NavIcon = styled.div`
background-image: url(${osun});
margin-right: 0.5rem;

`;
export const MobileIcon = styled.div`

    display: none;

    @media screen and (max-width: 960px){
        display:block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right:0 ;
        transform: translate(-100%, 60%);
        font-size: 1.8rem;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
`;

export const NavMenu = styled.ul`
display: flex;
align-items: center;
list-style: none;
//text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
/* display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100px;
        height: 500px;
        top: 80px;
        left: -100%;
        opacity:1;
        transition: all 0.5s ease; */

    @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100%;
        //list-style: none;
        height: 90vh;
        top: 80px;
        //right: -100%;
        right: ${({click}) => (click ? 0 : '-100%')};
        opacity:1;
        //transform: ${({open}) => open ? 'translateX(0)' : 'translateX(100%)'};
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        background: #101522; //rgb(35, 31,32);//
    }
`;

export const NavItem = styled.li`
height: 80px;
border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;

@media screen and (max-width: 960px){
    //visibility: hidden;
   // display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    //top:0;
    //right:0;
    //transform: translate(-100%, 60%);
    //font-size:1.8rem;
    //cursor: pointer;
}

&:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #4b59f7;
}
`;

export const NavLinks = styled(Link)`
color: #fff;
display:flex;
align-items: center;
text-decoration: none;
padding:0.5rem 1rem;
height: 100%;

@media screen and (max-width: 960px){
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;

    &:hover {
        color:#4b59f7;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }
}
`;

export const NavItemBtn = styled.li`
@media screen and (max-width: 960){
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px
}

`;

export const NavBtnLink= styled(Link)`
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;

`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue and ran into errors with your code example, which may be the cause of your issue. In particular:

```
const [click, setClick, isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
```

is not a valid setup for useState. Try splitting this into two separate useState calls like:

```
const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
```

As you had it in the original example, my IDE immediately flagged that line, and also informed me that isOpen was not initialized to anything, which threw major errors when I tried to click the button / blur it.

Comment: I just tried splitting the statement into two separate useState calls like you suggested and I don't see any changes. For some reason my IDE didn't flag that line.

Comment: If you console log or debug the handlers, what does the console tell you? Any error messages, or maybe it's hitting both handlers in a weird order? What happens if you remove the blur event and just focus on the click event?

Comment: The code compiles as it is and I'm not getting any errors. How can I go about debugging the handler? Removing the onBlur event doesn't change any functionality.

Comment: If it were me I would add console logs in each of the handlers, showing the value and which handler was called, and then check the logs on click to see if the values were what I expected. Looking at it again, I suspect that the handle event is being called twice, once from the MobileIcon and once from the NavIcon, which would mean the isOpen value swaps twice, landing back at the original value. Try removing one of them, maybe?